# If case equals something then subtract date

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Trying to write a query that checks if a column equals something.  If so, take the value of a date column then subtract by a certain value.

The query looks like this:

```
select
  v.voyage "Voyage"
 ,v.service "Service"
 ,to_char(vp.eta_date, 'MONTH dd, yyyy') "ETA"
 ,case 
    when v.service = "USA" then to_char(vp.eta_date, 'MONTH dd, yyyy') - 2
    else 'n/a'
    end as 'Notice'
from 
  table
// bunch of joins
```

When I run the above, I get an error that reads:

```
FROM keyword not found where expected
```

The error is pointing to the word 'Notice'.

I basically want to check if service is equal to 'USA', and if so, use the eta_date subtracted by 2 to give me the date in the Notice column.

If not, then just so 'N/A' in the Notice column.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: If `"USA"` is a literal value, it should be enclosed in single quotes, as in `'USA'`.

Comment: I still get the same error after making that update.

Comment: I just updated the end as to "Notice" to make it a literal.  Now I am getting the following error: "inconsistent datetypes: expteced NUMBER got CHAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of syntax errors and quote mixups that make this confusing. These are the rules for quotes (relevant for your code)

- Use single quotes for strings
- Use double quotes for column aliases

And then there is this part:
`to_char(vp.eta_date, 'MONTH dd, yyyy') - 2` which tells the sql engine to substract 2 from a string of format "MONTH dd, yyyy". You probably meant substract 2 days from the date (vp.eta_date) and then format it as "MONTH dd, yyyy" which can be written as `to_char(vp.eta_date - 2, 'MONTH dd, yyyy')`

Putting it all together gives

```
select
  v.voyage "Voyage"
 ,v.service "Service"
 ,to_char(vp.eta_date, 'MONTH dd, yyyy') "ETA"
 ,case 
    when v.service = 'USA' then to_char(vp.eta_date - 2, 'MONTH dd, yyyy')
    else 'n/a'
    end as "Notice"
from 
  table
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CHAR.

Comment: In the else, I added to_char('n/a') and it worked.  Thank you.